# F# - Rules for casting integers to floats?

Tags: f#

I am trying to understand F#'s type inference system and its policy for casting integer literals to floats is not clear to me.

This compiles. 3 and 4 are interpreted as floats.

```ml
let f (x: float) (y: float) = x + y
f 3 4
```

This does not compile:

```ml
let f (x: float) = x + 3
```

This kind of makes sense to me, ok, seems like a property of the type inference system that it can't simultaneously infer that 3 should be a float and that `+` should be a function float -> float -> float.

But this does compile:

```ml
let f (x: float) y = x + y
```

I'm having trouble putting these pieces together into a coherent theory of how type inference interacts with deciding the types of literals. What is going on here?

Comment: F# recently added casting int literals to doubles. So if target is known to be `double`, F# will treat literal as double. If target is unknown, then literal treated as it's default type, which is `int`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/casting-and-conversions#implicit-numeric-conversions

Comment: Indeed, as @JL0PD said: op_implicit in action since F# 6.0: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/FSharp-6.0/FS-1093-additional-conversions.md

Answer (score 1):

Type inference means the compiler will infer a type without you having to explicitly declare it. In your example

```
let f (x: float) y = x + y
```

the compiler infers y is a float, since you are adding it to x, which you have declared as a float. But with

```
let f (x: float) = x + 3
```

there is nothing to infer about '3', it's a numeric literal, in this case an integer. If this was C#, you could rely on the compiler to just do an implicit conversion from an integer to a float. But F# doesn't have implicit conversions - because that would interfere with type inference. So just make your constant here a float:

```
let f (x: float) = x + 3.0
```

Or better yet

```
let f x = x + 3.0
```

As now the compiler can infer that x is a float.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.
There are two possible ways of saying this, I'm not sure if there's a meaningful distinction, it seems like semantics to me. But either
1. F# does have implicit conversions from integers to floats
2. F# parses numeric literals in a context dependent way, interpreting them either as an integer or a float.
Let's use the language of 2. This is what my question is about. What are the rules for this context dependent interpretation?

Comment: When there are no types given, the operators default to int arguments. Once you specify that at least one of the identifiers has another compatible type, then type inference will make all unconstrained identifiers match the type. That is all clear. But there is a mechanism to allow op_implicit type conversion functions to be called, as outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/casting-and-conversions#arithmetic-types
In your code `f 3 4` works due to:
https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/FSharp-6.0/FS-1093-additional-conversions.md